# What is the purpose of ApplicationRef in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I don't understand the `ApplicationRef` class and its uses. What does it mean to have a "[reference to an Angular application running on a page](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef)"? When is this needed?

Please provide a small example using `ApplicationRef`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef

- allows to invoke application-wide change detection by calling `appRef.tick()`
- it allows to add/remove views to be included in or excluded from change detection using `attachView()` and `detachView()`
- provides a list of registered components and component types using `componentTypes` and `components`
  and some other change detection related information

Answer (score 16):

`ApplicationRef` contains reference to the root view and can be used to manually run change detection using [tick](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick) function

> Invoke this method to explicitly process change detection and its
>   side-effects.
>
> In development mode, tick() also performs a second change detection
>   cycle to ensure that no further changes are detected. If additional
>   changes are picked up during this second cycle, bindings in the app
>   have side-effects that cannot be resolved in a single change detection
>   pass. In this case, Angular throws an error, since an Angular
>   application can only have one change detection pass during which all
>   change detection must complete.

Here is an example:

```
@Component()
class C {
   property = 3;
   constructor(app: ApplicationRef, zone: NgZone) {
       // this emulates any third party code that runs outside Angular zone
       zone.runOutsideAngular(()=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
             // this won't be reflected in the component view
             this.property = 5;

             // but if you run detection manually you will see the changes
             app.tick();
          })
       })
```

Another application is to attach a dynamically created component view for change detection if it was created using a root node:

```
  addDynamicComponent() {
     let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SimpleComponent);

     let newNode = document.createElement('div');
     newNode.id = 'placeholder';
     document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newNode);

     const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
     this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
  }
```

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707/2545680) for more details.

Comment: I suggest to add some detailed information on registered components API and it would definitely be the absolute best answer :)