# Compile angular2+ component to dynamically created DOM element

Tags: angular, dom

I have a 3rd party library which dynamically creates a DOM element, I need to compile a component and insert it to the created DOM element.

I'm using component factory resolver and i know i can insert it to `ViewContainerRef`, but i'm not sure how to insert to plain DOM element created by outside angular lib.

```
onDynamicDomCreate: (e: GridChangeEvent) => {
            let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(UserDetailsComponent);
            e.sender.element.createComponent(factory); // <--- how to properly create component here?
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a DOM element when creating a component like this:

```
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(UserDetailsComponent);
const compRef = factory.create(injector, [], e.sender.element);
```

And also register the created view in the [ApplicationRef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583478/2545680), otherwise you won't have change detection for the component:
    appRef.attachView(compRef.hostView);