# Angular 4 access template element without template local variable

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I have a parent component (say `ParentComponent`) and I need to add many children components (say `ChildComponent1`, `ChildComponent2`, ... `ChildComponentN`) to it **dynamically**. Each component is different.

I followed this to solve my problem : [Angular 2 RC5-6 - Dynamically insert a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357195/angular-2-rc5-6-dynamically-insert-a-component)

But in order to access the template element (a simple `<div>`) that will hold my `ChildComponent`s through `@ViewChild`, I need to set a template local variable on this `<div>` element.

However, in my case, I can't do that because I can't set a template local variable with a *dynamically name*. So my `<div>` element is only characterized by an unique id attribute that is added dynamically (like `<div id="child1">`).

Is there any way to access my `<div>` element through the component implementation in typescript *without template local variable* ?

Comment: can you add a directive to the element? like `<div mydir...`?

Comment: @Maximus Yes I can add a directive to the `<div>` (but each `<div>` must have something unique in order to add the right `ChildComponent` template under the right `<div>` element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a directive `mydir` that will expose an element:

```
@Directive({selector: 'mydir'})
export class MyDir {
  @Input('mydir') id;
  constructor(public vc: ViewContainerRef) {

  }
}
```

and then apply it to the div:

```
<div [mydir]="child1">
<div [mydir]="child2">
```

and then query it from the parent component:

```
@ViewChildren(MyDir) children;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   const specificID = 'child1';
   const instance = children.find((c)=>{c.id === specificID});
   const vc = instance.vc;
}
```

Comment: I think that could works, but the `@ViewChildren` gives me a `QueryList<MyDir>`. I need a `ViewContainerRef` in order to add my child component template under the `<div>` element.

Do you have any idea on how I could : 
1) get a specific `<div>` element by the id through the directive ?
2) get the `ViewContainerRef` of this specific `<div>` element ?

Comment: @Dartz, see my edit. @ViewChildren will give you instances of `MyDir`, but on each instance you will find `vc` which will be a reference to the view container

Comment: That almost works, but for an unknown reason, the debugger shows that the id of the directive is always undefined (I am not very comfortable with directives). 

I have a *warning of my IDE* on the `@Input` line of the directive : 
`[tslint] In the class "MyDir", the directive input property "id" should not be renamed.Please, consider the following use "@Input() id: string" (no-input-rename)`. 

But if I write `@Input() id: string;`, I have an *angular error* on application loading : 
`Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'mydir' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`.

Comment: @Dartz, `tslint` is not a problem. Can you show you code? I don't know where you get `child1` and `child2`  values

Comment: Sure. [Directive](https://paste.ofcode.org/m72SuuW44y8YfV3q7c7jj8), [Template](https://paste.ofcode.org/eTpCrrYS57PLzHMMAqcE7e), [Component](https://paste.ofcode.org/YKVLm2Ck8uWazLJzH5AN2G). I have hardcoded the id in the template to simplify debugging.

Comment: @Dartz, no, in the template where you use `mydir`

Comment: I only use mydir (which is `cartDomain` in my code) in this line of [my template](https://paste.ofcode.org/eTpCrrYS57PLzHMMAqcE7e).

Comment: @Dartz, and does `options` have value on parent component instance?

Comment: Ok that's it. I thought that would set the id to "options" but no... Now if I set an `private options = "options"` property in my component, that works. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

If you have angular 4 you can use *ngComponentOutlet="dinamicCompomponent" for insert component dinamically

Comment: Yes, but I would have the same trouble. In fact, I need to access the children components in the typescript of the parent component in order to set up the children components properties (because `@Input` and `@Output` are not supported yet by `ngComponentOutlet`).

Comment: Use @ViewChild() in parent component

Comment: But `@ViewChild` needs a selector, which is the point of my question.