# can i load an angular 2 component into DOM from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
function injectAngular (){
    console.log("angular");
    document.body.innerHTML += '<app-root style="height:100%;width:100%"></app-root>'
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="injectAngular()" name="button">angular</button>
```

when i tried this approach angular was not able to recognize the selector . Is there a solution to solve this problem .

Comment: Can you please format the code .Also what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: are you trying to load a component dynamically in to an html?

Comment: you have a few options, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707/2545680) and [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99)

Comment: Please tell about the functionality you are trying to achieve along with what you have tried. So everyone can help you to give good approach and solution

Comment: `app-root` implies this is your root component, so it is the one component that must be bootstrapped via Angular. In theory, you could do what your asking but you would need to manually bootstrap *after* the component element has been inserted into the DOM. Once your root component is bootstrapped, you can then dynamically create child components (if needed). I suspect there is a better way to accomplish what you're looking for though. What are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: @Jbird. thanks for the reply . I'm trying to load an angular component for one of my view in my existing application which uses JS. So , for POC purpose i'm trying to inject my root component on click of a button .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of touching the InnerHTML directly, why not set up a view (using an ng-repeat element) that gets its values from a JSON value in your controller? You can very easily add new elements that way.