# Angular 5 dynamically insert a component into existing markup?

Tags: angular, dynamic

Here's my scenario. Users enter content via tinyMCE editor, and I display this content to the user in a component like so:

```
@Component({
    template: '
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
    '
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    content: string = "";

    constructor(private service: any){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.loadDetails().pipe(
            tap((result) => this.content = result)
        ).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Now the content from the server can be anything. So if the server returns this content:

`<p>This is my content from the server. <img src="..." /></p>`

Then my `DetailsComponent` output would look like this:

```
<h3>Description</h3>
<div>
    <p>This is my content from the server. <img src="..." /></p>
</div>
```

I want to write a component to replace any images with a custom component. How do you do this without using an existing #template reference?

Essential, it could look like this where my custom component wraps the image:

```
<h3>Description</h3>
<div>
    <p>This is my content from the server. <custom-component><img src="..." /></custom-component></p>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically what you need to do is create a dynamic component with the template you are fectching from the server. Is that right?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara Yup, this is what I'm needing

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by working off [this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357195/angular-2-dynamically-insert-a-component-into-a-specific-dom-node-without-using)

Here's how I solved the problem.

```
update() {

    let images = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img');

    for (let x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
        const img = images[x];

        let clone = img.cloneNode(true);
        // Important because angular removes all children of a node. 
        // So wrap the image, and then use the wrapper as the root node for the component to attach to
        $(img).wrap("<span />");
        let factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomComponent);
        let ref = factory.create(this.injector, [[clone]], img.parentNode); //use a clone as the projectable node, and use its parent (the wrapper span) as the rootNode

        this.applicationRef.attachView(ref.hostView);
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.components.push(ref); //save the references later so that I can destroy them
    }
}
```