# Add angular component to non angular third party component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add angular component to native DOM element which is created by third party, and I don't have ElementRef/ViewContainerRef to it?

We use some grid library, which builds grid with native JS. The library provides a callback where we get reference to native DOM element.
How I can use this reference as container for rendering angular component inside of it?

I searched over internet and saw many examples of manipulating DOM and creating components using ViewContainerRef and/or ElementRef, but I didn't found an answer how to add component to DOM element which is not created by angular.

Comment: Have you considered using an Angular grid? Using a JS grid will be possible but hacky.

Comment: We using DevExtreme for our UI. They do have angular support, but their grid has just angular wrapper over native JS grid and it's api not granular enough (or lack of support for some of our use cases). I'm looking to ways how i can customize it through angular. I think that I found possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707/1127918

Comment: That link is along the lines of the approach I was thinking if you have to do it that way. Have you reached out to DevExpress support? They may be able to suggest something.

Comment: @wlf yep, their answer was that hey does not support custom controls for our use case, but they also said, it's ok to clear existing HTML in specific element and insert other HTML. From there I started to look how to render angular component instead of writing plain HTML in innerHTML property or adding DOM elements with appendChild.