# Angular 13: Dynamically insert a component into a specific DOM node

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-dynamic-components

I need to achieve something like in this question
[Angular 2 Dynamically insert a component into a specific DOM node without using ViewContainerRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357195)

I got a task to use the plain google maps api within an angular/ionic project.
I want to add a button as a custom control to the map, and I want to use ionic-button for this and not create the button completely in plain javascript/typescript.

But as [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) got deprecated in Angular 13, what would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself the following solution.
In the component where I include the google map the following template is used

```
<div class="mapcontainer" #mapContainer>
   <ng-template #btnTemplate>
    <ion-button class="map-button" (click)="onClick()"> 
      {{toggleButtonText}}
    </ion-button>
  </ng-template>
  <div class="loading-indicator">
    <ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="!loaded" color="primary"></ion-spinner>
  </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen the ionic button is within a template that has a ref, so it is accessible as a view child in the angular component.
And then to add the button to the google map I do the following in the typescript component code.

```
    const btnViewRef = this.btnTemplate.createEmbeddedView();
    this.app.attachView(btnViewRef);

     const btnContainer = document.createElement('div');
     for (const node of btnViewRef.rootNodes) {
       btnContainer.appendChild(node);
     }

     this.map.controls
      [this.googleField.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(btnContainer);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: @Eliseo
This is the solution for my use case. But I still ask myself if there is also a solution to do it with a component class.

Comment: Have the same issue, so far I am using ComponentFactoryResolver as there doesn't seem to be a way to do it with new api :(